# Bind a form object to a ModelAttribute with a prefix?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a legacy application that contains lots of forms from a previous framework that required a prefix for the entity. For example, an Item object with a name would have a form field of:

```
<input name="item.name" ... />
```

In my spring controller, I use a ModelAttribute as normal:

```
@ModelAttribute Item item
```

But the binding fails because spring does not expect the prefix for the item. Is there some way I can tell spring to ignore the prefix and bind without having to create a wrapper object or having to change the prefix from every form field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsp as your view, you will also need to add `modelAttribute` in your form as well, and make sure that you have declared getters for your form fields in Item object. Ex: `getName()`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<form:form id="new-item-form"
            method="post"
            modelAttribute="item" ...>
   <input name="item.name" ... />
</form:form>
```

If you're using Thymeleaf , then you have to add its XML namespace to your html, and then you can access model attributes in views with Thymeleaf using **Spring EL** as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    ...
    <p th:text="${item.name}">Name</p>
    ...
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I was using Thymeleaf as the view which does not have that tag- but I don't think a front end solution would work since its the controller method that can't seem to bind with the prefix.

Comment: I thought you were using jsp for a legacy application :) will update my answer.